# Не могу выбрать между Yii2 и Laravel. Боюсь ошибиться, помогите!

Tags: php, laravel, yii2, yii

Я новичок в php разработке. Но уверенно изучаю и уже сносно пишу код. У меня есть свой проект, который относительно сложный. В нем свои кабинеты пользователей, констpуктор страниц, поддомены пользователей и магазин приёма платежей для клиента.

Боюсь вложить силы в разработку, чтобы потом понять, что выбрал не тот или слабый фреймворк. Не могу увидеть весь потенциал.

Что выбрать между Yii2 и Laravel 9.
Еще пугает эти постоянный релизы новых версий. YII3 И LARAVEL 10.

Как поступить в общем и почему? Очень благодарен буду за любой совет.

Помогите с выбором. Сбивают с толку обновления

Comment: Невозможно дать объективный ответ

Comment: ответ всегда один: делайте на том, что лучше всего знаете или нравится. всё

Comment: По крайней мере Laravel активно развивается и комьюнити у него точно больше. Версия yii3 постоянно задерживается-откладывается и вообще неясно, что с ней будет.

Comment: @u_mulder в yii2 тоже много и инфы и доков и форума и поддержки.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Да нет там нихрена, ни пакетов, ни толком ответов на банальные вопросы. У Laravel всё куда лучше, да и код пишется намного удобнее и проще без устаревшего всего.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar вы кажется ищете в параллельной вселенной. Давно работаю и ни одной проблемы не встретил. Абсолютно все интересующие ответы на вопросы нашёл без проблема что на русском,что на английском

Comment: Любой. Я пишу на трёх: Yii2/Yii1, Laravel, Symfony. Правда на Symfony всего лишь 8 месяцев писал API. Сейчас на нём у меня нет проектов. В основном Yii2 &  Laravel. Все три классные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как человек который писал на Yii2 больше 2-х лет, а после перешел на Laravel, сейчас использую 8 версию и не спешу переходить на 9.

Так вот... оба фреймворка дают тебе набор кубиков из которых ты что-то строишь и тут уже дело вкуса, что Yii2 что Laravel имеют огромны набор таких механизмов, но после того как я поюзал оба могу сказать что Laravel удобнее, чего стоит только система конфигов для приложения, идем дальше... роуты тоже намного удобнее чем в Yii2 и так можно перечислять еще очень долго, если тебе нравится Yii2-advanсed можно посмотреть в сторону apiato laravel, но не как механизм на котором писать, а как основу для своей структуры приложения, так как в апиато слишком много лишнего.

Еще плюс в сторону Laravel это огромный набор пакетов на любой цвет и вкус, но тут нужно понимать что не нужно юзать все подряд и на каждый чих который тебе нужно сделать, искать пакет который это уже реализует, парой лучше написать свой велосипед чем использовать чужой.

Comment: Огромное спасибо Вам за ответ!